# Tic Tac Toe in Google Sheets (Apps Script)

Tags: google-sheets-macros

I'm trying to create a two player tic tac toe (no AI). I have a cell that displays an X or an O depending on whos turn it is in cell J2. If it displays and X, then I want a checkbox, when checked, for that cell to be displayed as an X, and same for O.  Also, when the cells contents is deleted, I want the cell to revert to the FALSE Boolean on the checkbox(second else if). I'm pretty sure my problem is in my IF, but I am not completely sure.

```
function onEdit(TTT2) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var Range = ss.getActiveSelection();
  var Turn = SpreadsheetApp.getrange("J2").getValue();
  if(Range = ('TRUE') && Turn == ('X')) {
    spreadsheet.getActiveSelection().setValue("X"); 
  }else if(Range = ('TRUE') && Turn == ('O')){
    spreadsheet.getActiveSelection().setValue("O"); 
  }else if(Range = (''))
    spreadsheet.getActiveSelection().setValue("TRUE");
}
```

Edit: Found the (an?) error, it doesn't recognize the getrange. Which begs the question:  How do I set the value of a cell to a variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help, it will check if the range is in the first three columns and rows, and then set the value to X or O and change the turn. Instead of working with getting the SpreadsheetApp, I used the e from onEdit(e) which gives you a more direct path to the selected area and its value.

```
//Set board between a specific range. 

function onEdit(e) {
  if(e){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var range = e.range;

  //Check that its in the begining range
  if(range.getColumn() < 4 && range.getRow() < 4) {
    //Get the turn
    var turnRange = ss.getRange("J2");
    var turn = turnRange.getValue();

    //If the checkbox is checked
    if(range.getValue() == true){
      if(turn == 'X') {
        //set the box to X and change turn to O
        range.setValue("X");
        turnRange.setValue("O");
      }else if(turn == 'O'){
        //Set box to O and change turn to X
        range.setValue("O"); 
        turnRange.setValue("X");
      }
    }
    }
   }
}
```